# jquery DataTables sorting incorrectly

Tags: jquery, sql, datatables

I have a .net core project, using entity framework and jquery Data Tables. I pull a table from my sql database, sorted by Name, and everything is fine. When I add the data table to it, it sorts it incorrectly. It does half of the items (not exactly half, just a first bit of them) A-Z, then starts over at A again all over again. so like

Adam

Alex

Ben

Caroline

...

Victoria

Xander

Zeke

Aaron

Andrew

Bennet

...

Yolanda

The data in the table looks fine, I can't see any weird encoding. Its fine when I order it using entity framework. But when I add the datatable functionality it doesn't work.

The Datatable code looks like this

```
 var itemTable= $(".mytable").DataTable({
            aoColumnDefs: [
                { orderable: false, aTargets: [6] },
                { width: "40px", aTargets: [1] },
                { width: "70px", aTargets: [2] },
                { visible: false, aTargets: [10, 12] },
                { orderable: true, "targets": [[0, "asc"]]}
            ]
    });
```

Any places to look are greatly appreciated!

**Update:** I copied the whole sql table into a different db (local) and tried it there... worked fine. Something weird in the encoding that got stripped when I copied it into a CSV and back into a different table? but I can't see any characters in the db that are not regular characters

Answer (score 0):

I found it! There were hidden quotation marks on some of the entries in SQL! There was a trailing or leading space being added on some items, which made sql add the double quotes.

I found them by doing select * from mytable, right clicking on the results and clicking save as, then chose CSV file. Opened that CSV in Notepad++ and they appeared

I fixed all rows by running this query:

```
update People set Name = LTRIM(RTRIM(Name))
```